# Looping through a 2D char array to check values

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

How would one go about going through a 2D char array (char[25][75]), and check to see if all locations in the array have a certain character value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two nestled loops. One iterating over the first dimension, the other over the second.

like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {

     /** check if array[i][j] contains your desired value **/

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][] arr = ...;
for (char[] subArray : arr)
    for(char current : subArray)
    {
        //your check code here
    }
```